# Tab Content not changing

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I am trying to make different tabs in a page all with different content in the body. However when I click on a new tab the body is not changing. Anyone have any advice? It changes the pages but the body of each is all the same and I'm not sure why. Not sure if it is how I have the tabs set up within the html or something that needs to be changed with java. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./common/res.css"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Room Reservation</title>
</head>
<header>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./common/tab.js"></script>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul class="tab-links">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Stage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Studio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3">Session</a></li>
        </ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
        <form>
            Room Selection:<br>
            <select name="room">
                <option value="">Select Room</option>
                <option value="stage">Stage Access</option>
                <option value="grip">Grip Closet</option>
                <option value="grid">Grid</option>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
        <p>Studio</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab3" class="tab">
        <p>Session</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links li').on('click', function(e)  {
    tabs(jQuery(this).attr('data-toggle'));
    jQuery(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });`

    function tabs(tab) {
        jQuery('.tab-content .tab').hide()
        jQuery('.tab-content').find(tab).show();
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>



/*----- Tabs -----*/
.tabs {
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
}

/*----- Tab Links -----*/
/* Clearfix */
.tab-links:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    content:'';
}

.tab-links li {
    margin:0px 5px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}

    .tab-links a {
        padding:9px 15px;
        display:inline-block;
        border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
        background:#7FB5DA;
        font-size:16px;
        font-weight:600;
        color:#4c4c4c;
        transition:all linear 0.15s;
    }

    .tab-links a:hover {
        background:#a7cce5;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

li.active a, li.active a:hover {
    background:#fff;
    color:#4c4c4c;
}

/*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
.tab-content {
    padding:15px;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    background:#fff;
}

    .tab {
        display:none;
    }

    .tab.active {
        display:block;
    }
```

Comment: <select> tag is not closed

Comment: R.I.P....the simple things. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is your jquery code correct, some parenthesis were not correctly closed

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function tabs(tab) {
    jQuery('.tab-content .tab').hide()
    jQuery('.tab-content').find(tab).show();
  }


$('.tabs .tab-links li').on('click', function(e)  {
    tabs($(this).attr('data-toggle'));
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');



  });
});
```

Result: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2cn743r/)